# Is my magsave power adaptor dead?

Tags: macbook-pro, charger

Last night, I heard a spark noise while my mac power adaptor was connected, and the charger stopped charging my machine. There was no light on the connector. I should also say that the cable attaching to the adaptor was torn. So after reading instructions for dismantling the charger, I cracked it open and cut the cable before the plastic  piece inside the charger. Then, I tested if the AC charger was having any output DC voltage with a multimeter. But it did not detect any. Now, do I have to assume that the unit is dead or is there some fuse which needs to be replaced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [fuse](http://www.righto.com/2015/11/macbook-charger-teardown-surprising.html) in the charger, but replacing fuse is not recommended.

And this is [not the only surge protection unit](https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/69728/After+powersurge+no+light+on+magsafe+no+charge.+Board+or+PwrSupply). I recommend to test with another working charger and your mac and if your mac works well with another charger, then get another Apple charger.

Comment: Thanks for replying! Would you tell the reason why not replacing it?

Comment: I think there can be some fault on laptop side: damaged input connector, etc.